# Executing a function in a dictionary | Python 3

Tags: python, dictionary

So I am making a program in python 3.6 that selects and executes a specific function based on the `user_input`.

The code can properly decide what function to execute, just not actually execute it. The functions also work

```
def addition():
    1+1

user_input = input("What operator do you wish to use?")

myOperators = {"Addition":addition}

if user_input in myOperators:
    myOperators.get(user_input)
```

Using this code the function `addition()` never executes. However, I can check that it selects the correct value, because if I do this:

```
if user_input in myOperators:
    print(myOperators.get(user_input))
```

it prints `<function addition at 0x7f0973026620>`

Comment: You have to call the function so `myOperators.get(user_input)()` (with a call at the end).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python treats functions as object which can be passed around and stored in lists and dictionaries.  To actually call the function you need to use parenthesis after the object.

In your case `myOperators.get(user_input)` returns the function object, so it would become

```
myOperators.get(user_input)()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
I've been struggling with this for days.

Comment: Should probably use `__getitem__` (i.e. square brackets) instead of `get` because a possible `KeyError` will be easier to debug than `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`.